# Automatically set maximum number of map tasks per node to the number of cores?

Tags: hadoop

I'm working on setting up a hadoop cluster where the nodes are all fairly heterogeneous, i.e. they each have a different number of cores. Currently I have to manually edit the `mapred-site.xml` on each node to fill in `{cores}`:

```
<property>
    <name>mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum</name>
    <value>{cores}</value>
</property>
```

Is there an easier way to to this when I add new nodes? Most of the other values are some default and the maximum map tasks is the only thing that changes from node to node.

Answer (score 3):

If you're comfortable with some scripting then the following will give you the number of 'processors' for each machine (which mean different things to different architectures but is more or less what you want):

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | wc -l
```

Then you can use `sed` or some equivalent to update your mapred-site.xml file according to the output of this.

So putting this all together:

```
CORES=`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | wc -l`
sed -i "s/{cores}/$CORES/g" mapred-site.xml
```

A footnote, but you probably don't want to configure the number of mappers and the number of reducers each to the number of cores, more so that you probably want to split them between the two types, and have a core spare for data node and task tracker etc.

Comment: Thanks. I knew I could run some sort of script to do it, but I was hoping for some sort of hadoop variable that I could drop in. Or at least a more sensible default than 2.

Comment: You could amend the TaskTracker source code to interpret a formula in mapred-site.xml (`$CORES/2-1` for example) - but you'd preferably also need to find a Java way to determine the number of cores.